# Uncaught RuntimeException on laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am facing an error in Laravel 6. How can I solve this?

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Directory name must not be
> empty. in
> D:\Xampp\htdocs\tolet\vendor\symfony\finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php:54
> Stack trace: #0
> D:\Xampp\htdocs\tolet\vendor\symfony\finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php(54):
> RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('', 4096) #1
> D:\Xampp\htdocs\tolet\vendor\symfony\finder\Finder.php(669):
> Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('',
> 4096, false) #2
> D:\Xampp\htdocs\tolet\vendor\symfony\finder\Finder.php(571):
> Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder->searchInDirectory('') #3
> D:\Xampp\htdocs\tolet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration.php(76):
> Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder->getIterator() #4
> D:\Xampp\htdocs\tolet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration.php(59):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration->getConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
> #5 D:\Xampp\htdocs\tolet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\I in D:\Xampp\htdocs\tolet\vendor\symfony\finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php
> on line 54

Comment: when did the error occur?

Comment: Hi and welcome on StackOverflow. Your questions doesn't provide any details about your code, when the exception is thrown, or what you did to try and resolve it.
Putting so more input into the question might lead to better answers. Perhaps putting the stack trace as a code block (wrap it with triple backticks) is already a good start.

Comment: In every step. When try to access page, or run any command in the terminal, like update composer, clear cache, etc. @Aless55

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. But the fact is, I can't understand where the error occurs, truly, this is the first time I am facing this error. So I'm not sure which codes need to be shared. If someone wants any specific code, then I can share it. @DannyVanDerSluijs

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that a directory name is empty. You will need to make sure that the directory name in use has a value. Check your configuration for directory names and see whether there is any of them not configured. Ask your teammates whether some new configuration items were added that they did not let you know about so far.

But most importantly, debug your code, at the very least log some values while you are working on this at the lines pointed out by the stack trace to find out what's missing. Once you know what's missing, just make sure it will not be missing at the next load.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 
According to the Laravel file structure, the error occurred at this file: vendor\symfony\finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php
I got this error the first time. So I am not sure which directory it's called.

Comment: @JahidulIslam that's the deepest level of the error, but all the lines in the stack trace might be helpful. Somewhere you might have some clue about what is attempted to be found. If you could edit your question and add some code that you have around the places the stack trace points to, that would be helpful.